# Amenable to suggestion

Tags: meaning, formality, redundancy

I rather like the phrase "amenable to suggestion"

You can attach it to things easily:

> My political views, amenable to suggestion, ...

But I'm afraid it may be redundant. According to [this definition:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20amenable)

> (of a person) open and responsive to suggestion; easily persuaded or
>   controlled.
>
> (of a thing) capable of being acted upon in a particular
>   way; susceptible to.

I think it should be fine because "amenable" only involves suggestion when describing people. But according to [this definition:](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/amenable)

> open or susceptible to suggestion; likely to listen, cooperate, etc.

it does involve suggestion.

In a *formal context* is "amenable to suggestion" too redundant? Is it redundant at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think it redundant.

Comment: Being amenable just means being open. Is *open to suggestion* redundant? No. See @sevensideddie's answer: one is generally not just amenable; one is amenable to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**amenable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amenable): Open and responsive to suggestion; easily
>   persuaded or controlled: *‘parents who have amenable children’*
>
> More example sentences
>
> *‘Therefore our interest in a publicly neutral chairperson is solely focused on creating the most amenable context for conducting the
>   discussion.’*
>
> *‘Supt Hussey had always been co-operative, diligent and amenable in
>   his work, she said.*
>
> Plus many more.

"Amenable to suggestion" is redundant based on the "suggestion" part of the definition above.

In addition to being redundant, your example indicates that *your views* are **amenable**. You can be amenable, i.e., open and responsive to suggestion, with regard to your political views; *your political views* themselves cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Even regarding a person, *amenable* isn't unambiguous and benefits from specifying what one is amenable to.

Without specifying, merely saying one is "amenable" leaves it unclear what sort of influence is being described: it may means one is amenable to suggestion, or perhaps instead amenable to control. Those are two very different situations, and different statements about the person: being amenable to suggestion says that one is consciously agreeable, while being amenable to control suggests a much less capable person.

*Amenable* by itself is more general, and hence better to describe someone's personality. Meanwhile, when describing a situation, it is better and less ambiguous to be specific about what one is amenable to, especially if it is a temporary quality of the person rather than temperamental.